# Magento 2.4.3-p1 i can't upload images, The file was not uploaded

Tags: product-images, media-images, magento2.4.3.p1

After upgrading from Magento 2.3.7-p2 to Magento 2.4.3-P1 I can't upload images, in Magento admin, I get this error message: `The file was not uploaded`

In `var/log/exception.log` file, i see this error:

`main.CRITICAL: The file was not uploaded. {"exception":"[object] (DomainException(code: 666): The file was not uploaded. at ../../../vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php:228)"} []`

I am using an Apache 2.4 server, with Linux CentOS 7.9 and PHP 7.4.28

I already checked folder permissions and in theory, they are well configured.

If someone knows how to solve it, I appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try

sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/project/generated/code
sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/project/pub/static/*
sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/project/var/*

Comment: Are images are uploading to vanilla Magento?Did you checked image's property?

Comment: @Paul Fan, yes, i cleared that directories.

Comment: @Ankit, yes, i tested with a clean magento 3.4.3-p1 installation, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

After trying it in several ways without success, I found a possible solution, although I don't know if it is a definitive solution.

I had to modify the php.ini file for the version of php I'm using. This worked for me with the global server file, not at the user/account level.

In the php.ini file i have this lines:

```
; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not specified).

; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir

;upload_tmp_dir =
```

Uncomment the last line and add the /tmp directory, in my case:

```
upload_tmp_dir = "/tmp"
```

then restart the PHP-FPM service

Uncommenting the rule fixes the problem. , but i have the doubt, if this may imply a security problem in the server and why this problem was not generated with magento 2.4.2 or 2.4.3, If anyone has more information on these details, I appreciate the help.